# How to save file with user name by using window.open in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

I am using `window.open('file-path')` to download file , i want to download the file by user name. but the downloaded file name is set as original file name that we are uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in client-side code can influence the filename the browser will save a file as when the download is trigged via `window.open`.

It will generate a file name based on the URL unless [a `Content-Disposition` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#as_a_response_header_for_the_main_body) suggests a different one.

Client-side code can influence it only when trigged by clicking a link (which can be done programmatically with [the click method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)) that has [a `download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes) (and only when the request is a [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) request).